# Performing grid search with a predefined validation set Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

This question has been asked several times before. But I get an error when following the answer

First I specify which part is the training set and the validation set as follows.

```
my_test_fold = []


for i in range(len(train_x)):
    my_test_fold.append(-1)

 for i in range(len(test_x)):
    my_test_fold.append(0)
```

And then gridsearch is performed.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit
param = {
 'n_estimators':[200],
 'max_depth':[5],
 'min_child_weight':[3],
 'reg_alpha':[6],
    'gamma':[0.6],
    'scale_neg_weight':[1],
    'learning_rate':[0.09]
}




gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator = XGBClassifier( 
    objective= 'reg:linear', 
    seed=1), 
param_grid = param, 
scoring='roc_auc',
cv = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=my_test_fold),
verbose = 1)


gsearch1.fit(new_data_df, df_y)
```

But I get the following error

```
 object of type 'PredefinedSplit' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
cv = PredefinedSplit(test_fold=my_test_fold)
```

with

```
cv = list(PredefinedSplit(test_fold=my_test_fold).split(new_data_df, df_y))
```

The reason is that you may need to apply the [split method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit.split) to actually get the split into training and testing (and then transform it from an iterable object to a list object).

Answer (score -1):

The [`hypopt` Python package](https://github.com/cgnorthcutt/hypopt) (`pip install hypopt`), for which I am an author, was created for this exact purpose: parameter optimization with a validation set. It works with scikit-learn models and can be used with Tensorflow, PyTorch, Caffe2, etc.

```
# Code from https://github.com/cgnorthcutt/hypopt
# Assuming you already have train, test, val sets and a model.
from hypopt import GridSearch
param_grid = [
  {'C': [1, 10, 100], 'kernel': ['linear']},
  {'C': [1, 10, 100], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},
 ]
# Grid-search all parameter combinations using a validation set.
opt = GridSearch(model = SVR(), param_grid = param_grid)
opt.fit(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val)
print('Test Score for Optimized Parameters:', opt.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Edit: Has something changed with hypopt to cause the sudden recent downvotes? Some feedback would help as hypopt solves this exact problem and if there is an issue, we should fix it.

Comment: Does hypout allow specifying a pipeline instead of just a classifier?

Comment: As long as `.score()`, `.pred()`, `.pred_proba()`, and `.fit()` are defined.

Comment: Eventually figured it out. Thanks :)